# Change Arch Linux Gnome Desktop Default Icon Size

Tags: icons, size, desktop, gnome, archlinux

So I've done some searching around and all I can find is how to change the size one at a time (right click on file, click change icon size, drag from one corner to adjust the size). I also could only find stuff with Nautilus and one for Ubuntu.  And that gets a bit annoying since the default icon size is way to big. Is there a way to set the default size for the desktop icons? I'm using Arch Linux OS with gnome and gnome extra.  It took me a while to figure out how to get the icons to show up on the desktop but I think they're way to big.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view default-zoom-level 'small'`